# how can i execute remote console applications in windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, remote

I would like to know how I can run remote applications on Windows Machines. Until now I have been using Windows Powershell remote, that works fine, but only to execute cmdlets. I want to be able to execute any command line application, like launch a Vim session, a Diskpart utility, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the **[psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553)** utility from SysInternals to run commands on remote computers.

The syntax to launch a remote command prompt is `psexec \\REMOTE-PC cmd`.

Comment: if the computer don't belong to the same local network,  what are the options? I try to use the IP address but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by 'local network'.  If the machine is not part of your authentication domain, you'll need to supply credentials.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by 'local network'.  If the machine is not part of your authentication domain, you'll need to supply credentials.    PSExec -? will give you the parameters.

Comment: @msjr The double backslash is still needed even if you are using IP address ("psexec 10.15.10.15 cmd"). And as RobW says: You can supply credentials by using the -p and -u parameters.